# Can I repost my question to WolframCommunity if it is not answered here for a long time?

Tags: discussion

If I asked a question here at SE and there is no answer for it for a while, can I repost to WolframCommunity? If I can, how long should I wait before I can repost to WolframCommunity?

Comment: You are free to do what you want really, but if one posts a question to more than one place, it is a common courtesy to indicate so, and give a link to other place. This way, someone do not waste their time trying to help you, when the question has been answered somewhere else or being discussed there. So you put the link on both places saying this question is also there...